# How to pass db name on run time in kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have tried create DatabaseOpenHelper in kotlin. it doesn't allow me to pass db name on run time.

```
class DatabaseOpenHelper (context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "mydb.db", null, 4) {
   val TAG = javaClass<DatabaseOpenHelper >().getSimpleName()
   val TABLE = "logs"

   companion object {
       public val ID: String = "_id"
       public val TIMESTAMP: String = "TIMESTAMP"
       public val TEXT: String = "TEXT"
   }
   ..... other methods
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Put the db name on constructor? `(context: Context)` -> `(context: Context, name: String)`,  `SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "mydb.db", null, 4)` -> `SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, null, 4)`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor argument

```
class DatabaseOpenHelper (context: Context, name: String) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, null, 4) {
```